# How to make my facebook app public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

How to make my Facebook app public?

I'am able to access my app through redirecting but when I access it with others' credentials, it is showing this app is in development mode, you cannot access.

How to change that to public mode?

Comment: Your question isn't related with Java or JSP. Java is a programming language.

Answer (score 16):

In your App settings, go to "Status & Review" and flip the switch where it says: "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?".

If the switch is disabled, go to "Settings" > "Basic", enter a "Contact Email" and click on "Save Changes" to enable it.

Comment: I'm facing another problem. That is I'm using the graph as this "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?". But whenever i give a new user data, it is returning me previous user's data. Till the token expires. After Expiring, if i try it is giving me the user's data whom i'm requesting. Can you please suggest any idea??... @luschn

Comment: that´s a completely different question, i saw that you have opened another thread for it anyway.

Comment: Please comment on my question @luschn.. I'm a beginner.

Comment: as i said, it´s a different question. you opened another thread for it, so wait until people respond over there. be patient.

Comment: It is say you must add valid email address